# something not straightforward for me in CONDLET macro in OnLisp

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I don't understand the purpose of the 1st LET in **condlet-clause** below.

```
`(,(car cl) (let ,(mapcar #'cdr vars)
```

Is this necessary since it does not define specific value here?
It just declare the local variables instead. Why bother to do this?

```
(defmacro condlet (clauses &body body)
      (let ((bodfn (gensym))
            (vars (mapcar #'(lambda (v) (cons v (gensym)))
                          (remove-duplicates
                           (mapcar #'car
                                   (mappend #'cdr clauses))))))
        `(labels ((,bodfn ,(mapcar #'car vars)
                     ,@body))
            (cond ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (cl)
                                (condlet-clause vars cl bodfn))
                            clauses)))))

(defun condlet-clause (vars cl bodfn)
  `(,(car cl) (let ,(mapcar #'cdr vars)
                 (let ,(condlet-binds vars cl)
                   (,bodfn ,@(mapcar #'cdr vars))))))

(defun condlet-binds (vars cl)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (bindform)
              (if (consp bindform)
                  (cons (cdr (assoc (car bindform) vars))
                        (cdr bindform))))
          (cdr cl)))
```

Comment: `mappend` isn't part of Common Lisp.  Is that supposed to be `mapcan`?

Comment: Can you show an example of how `condlet` is supposed to be used so that we can have some good input data to use for macroexpansion?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor All the sample code from On Lisp are listed here: http://ep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/onlisp.lisp

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yeah, I'm not sure why there's `mappend`;  it's equivalent to `mapcan`, except that it could run into the maximum argument list length limit.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It also doesn't presume that the function returns mutable lists, unlike `mapcan`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yup.  that would explain it;  I had to check the docs.  I was thinking that `mapcan` used append and `mapcon` used `nconc`.  That's **not** what the difference is.

Comment: mappend is a function defined in the book which just combines mapcar and append. Nothing new but appends the lists returned by mapcar.

Comment: @user1461328 Well, yes, we were just discussing about how it differs from `mapcan` (which uses `nconc` instead of `append`). The main difference is that `append` copies the incoming lists, and `nconc` mutates the incoming lists. The latter is more performant but can only be used if the lists are linear-update; the former is usable everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this implementation of `CONDLET`](http://common-lisp.net/project/bdb/qbook/mycl-util/api/macro_005FMYCL-UTIL_003A_003ACONDLET.html), `condlet` can be used like this:

```
(condlet (((= 1 2) (x 1) (y 2))
          ((= 1 1) (x 2) (y 1))
          (t (x 3) (z 3)))
  (list x y z))
```

Notice that there are *three* variables that appear in the body part, `x`, `y`, and `z`, but each of those clauses only binds two: the first and second bind `x` and `y`, and the third binds `x` and `z`.  By doing

```
(let (x y z)
  (let <bindings from actual clause>
    (bodyfn x y z)))
```

the macro guarantees that `x`, `y`, and `z` all have default values of `nil`. The `<bindings from actual clause>` will lexically shadow the variables that the actual clause is responsible for binding.  That's a bit of a simplification, though.  To see what's actually happening, let's look at the macroexpansion of that example:

```
(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(condlet (((= 1 2) (x 1) (y 2))
                                  ((= 1 1) (x 2) (y 1))
                                  (t (x 3) (z 3)))
                         (list x y z))))
;=>
(LABELS ((#:G973 (Y X Z)                   ;  g973 = bodfn
           (LIST X Y Z)))
  (COND
   ((= 1 2)
    (LET (#:G974 #:G975 #:G976)            ; y(g974) = nil, x(g975) = nil, z(g976) = nil
      (LET ((#:G975 1) (#:G974 2))         ; x = 1, y = 2
        (#:G973 #:G974 #:G975 #:G976))))   ; (bodfn y x z)
   ((= 1 1)
    (LET (#:G974 #:G975 #:G976)            ; y = nil, x = nil, z = nil
      (LET ((#:G975 2) (#:G974 1))         ; x = 2, y = 1
        (#:G973 #:G974 #:G975 #:G976))))   ; (bodfn y x z)
   (T
    (LET (#:G974 #:G975 #:G976)            ; y = nil, x = nil, z = nil
      (LET ((#:G975 3) (#:G976 3))         ; x = 3, z = 4
        (#:G973 #:G974 #:G975 #:G976)))))) ; (bodfn y x z)
```